# I can't login to Ubuntu?

Tags: password

When I want to log into my account, Ubuntu claims my password is wrong.

Even after a fresh install, Ubuntu still does not accept my password at login.

What is wrong here and how should I proceed?

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password

Comment: @EliahKagan I converted my comments to an answer. Yesterday the question was put on hold and not reopened yet, so I could not write it as answer then.

Comment: Pola Khali: If my answer solves your problem, please don't hesitate to accept it by clicking on the grey tick symbol below the vote counter. This means "Yes, this is the answer that solved my problem best." Please do also add to your question ([edit] it) whether this problem occurred on the first login after the installation (as I assume) or some time later. That is not really clear yet. Thank you! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Do you use symbols or special letters in your password? I once had a problem with the same symptoms you described. In my case, I set Ubuntu's keyboard layout during the installation to the correct setting (German for me) and entered my password into the installation wizard with the correct German layout.
After the initial reboot I wanted to login again and Ubuntu refused to accept the password.

I tried to **open the on-screen keyboard** (from the accessibility menu - that is the stick-man symbol in your panel on top of your screen) and saw that a completely different keyboard layout was set, so of course I was unable to enter the correct password, as the labels on my keyboard did not match the characters they were interpreted as.

**To log in, you can just use this on-screen keyboard and enter the password by clicking.**

Another possibility would be to reinstall it again (or at least remember this for the next installation!) and just use a password like "123456789". Numbers only is the best, because they should be placed on the same buttons in every keyboard layout.

Of course you will not have to use the simple password from now on or type it always on-screen. **Once you managed to login, you must go to the System Settings and correctly chose your keyboard layout.** This time the setting will stay persistent and you should be able to log in in future without any problems.